# How does keys method work for dictionaries in python

Tags: python, object

How does .keys method return a list of keys in parenthesis?
I mean after getting a list of keys how does python put this list into parenthesis? If I want to write a function that returns list in parenthesis how should I implement that? For example:
def foo():
l=[1,2]
what should I write so that when I call my function it returns this list l in parenthesis? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "in parenthesis"? In Python 3.x you get a view object: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

Comment: Are you thinking of a `tuple` instead of a `list`? Then `var = (1, 2)`. `tuple` is basically an immutable list (that is, you can't change it so any methods that would change it are missing).

Comment: Don't confuse the values with the representation of the values. `[1, 2, 3]` is a visual representation of a list, but the list itself has no square brackets and commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be new to Python. If what you want to do is return a tuple `(1, 2)` from a list `var =[1, 2]` you can apply the `tuple()` function:

```
>>> var = tuple([1, 2])
>>> var
(1, 2)
```

In actual fact the `dict.keys()` fujnction returns a special iterator  called a view, but as the `tuple` function takes any iterator as an argument the `tuple` function will still work for a view.

```
>>> d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> tuple(d.keys())
(1, 2)
```

If this isn't what you want perhaps you can edit the question to explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I mean is if I have a dict with only one key, which for example is 5, when I write in python print(duct.keys()), it prints dict_keys([5]), so I am interested in how does python puts this list [5] inside the parenthesis

Comment: That's just the textual representation of the iterator - they way Python tries to represent it in a meaningful way. It tells you that the object is a `dict_keys` iterator, with a list of keys containing only one member. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(l):  
    
  return tuple(l.keys())
```

A simple test to check the result:

```
print(foo({1:"one", 2: "two"}))

print(foo({1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four", "anykey":"anyvalue"}))
```